# Why does JVM allocated Heap size increase after heap dump?

Tags: java, heap-dump

I'm monitoring a JVM process and I notice every time I perform a heap-dump it increases my allocated heap size to that application. This is certainly not expected and it's not something I want when I do a heap dump. What is the reason and is there a way to prevent it?

For example, if I check `jstat` before Heap dump here is what I get:

```
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
52224.0 54784.0  0.0    0.0   519680.0 396674.9 10765824.0  75678.9   65920.0 62151.2 8576.0 7827.8      8    0.057   7      1.776    1.832
```

I do a Heap dump using `jcmd`:

```
jcmd <pid> GC.heap_dump heap.bin
```

and check `jstat` again it looks like heap size allocated has increased (looking at OC column):

```
S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
52224.0 54784.0  0.0    0.0   519680.0 45402.9  13836800.0  75711.1   65920.0 62168.7 8576.0 7830.9      9    0.060   8      1.944    2.004
```

I confirm I see the same thing in Java VisualVM (each step up is after a heap dump):

[image]

I've found I can get a heap dump without this increase when I use `jmap` command without the `live` option. But why does this happen in the first place?